# Setting the Density To Any Non-Zero value causes many variables to go weird

Tags: c++, box2d

I have been trying to code a framework to make it easier for me to code games, but when working on the particle system I ran into an error. Whenever I chose to change the density to anything other than zero it would make many variables such as the position change to weird numbers for example the min or max value of an int. This worked fine with my object class so I am confused why it isn't working with the particle class.

Here is the code:

Particle Class

```
class Particle{
 private:
  int scale;
  int width, height;

  b2Body *body;
  b2BodyDef bodyDef;
  b2FixtureDef fixture;
  b2PolygonShape shape;

  float friction, density, restitution;

 public:
  Particle(int width, int height, float friction, float density, float restitution, int scale);

  int Create(int x, int y);
  void ApplyImpulse(b2Vec2 v) { if(body) body->ApplyLinearImpulse(/*inserts v*/);
  SDL_Rect GetScaledPosition();

  b2Body *GetBody(){return body;}
  void SetBody(b2Body *sBody) {body = sBody;}
  b2BodyDef *GetBodyDef() {return &bodyDef;}
  b2FixtureDef *GetFixtureDef() {return &fixture;}
};

Particle::Particle(int width, int height, float friction, float density, float restitution, int scale){
  this->friction = friction;
  this->density = density;
  this->restitution = restitution;
  //Adds other variables the same way
}

SDL_Rect Particle::GetScaledPosition() {
  SDL_Rect rect;
  rect = { (int)((body->GetPosition().x * scale) - (width / 2)), (int)((body->GetPosition().y * scale) - (height / 2)), (int)width, (int)height };
  return rect;
}

int Particle::Create(int x, int y){
  bodyDef.position.Set((x + (width/2))/scale, (y + (height/2))/scale);
  shape.SetAsBox((width/2)/scale, (height/2)/scale);
  fixture.shape = &shape;
  bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
  fixture.friction = friction;
  fixture.density = density;
  fixture.restitution = restitution;
  return 0;
}
```

App Class

```
int App::SpawnParticle(Particle *p, int x, int y, float dX, float dY){
    Particle *tmp;
    tmp = new Particle(*p);

    //Body Setup
    tmp->Create(x, y);

    tmp->SetBody(world->CreateBody(tmp->GetBodyDef()));
    tmp->GetBody()->CreateFixture(tmp->GetFixtureDef());
    tmp->GetBody()->SetUserData(tmp);

    //Inital Impulse
    tmp->ApplyImpulse(b2Vec2(dX, dY));

    particles.push_back(tmp);   
}
```

Main File

```
#include<iostream>
#include "App.h"
#include "Particle.h"

using namespace std;

App a = new App(/*Basic Setup*/);
Particle p = new Particle(10, 10, 0.3f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 12);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
     App.SpawnParticle(&p, 10, 10, 0, -10);
     while(true){
         //printed out values such as 2,147,483,647 when checking position
     }
}
```

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve], your question is not yet ready for SO without that. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: We still need a [mre]. You presumably have undefined behaviour somewhere. Dangling pointers would be a likely suspect

Comment: None of your shown code has an example of setting the density to ANY value, let alone non-zero, or shows any way for us to observe your position, etc, getting wonky.

Comment: `App a = new App` - you've never compiled this have you?

Comment: No it is just that it seemed like I would add a lot of unnecessary code to the example